# AngularJS. Can see variable in console.log but cant use it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I've requested to the server by $resourse.query method and got data response.

```
habitantsResource.query(
        {
            $filter: "startswith(Email, '" + vm.email + "')",
        },
        function (data) {
            vm.habitantId = data[0].habitantId;
            console.log(data[0].habitantId)
        });
```

value appears at console

but vm.habitantId stayed empty.

How to get this value?

Comment: How do you determine that `vm.habintantId` is empty?

Comment: show your code with `habitantId`

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey There is a code for this controller [link](https://github.com/nucknine/AngularWebApiRK/blob/master/WebClient/app/habitants/habitantEditCtrl.js) in this repo u can see the whole code for the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript and thus AngularJS is case sensitive. You are trying to access `vm.habitantid: {{vm.habitantid}}` in your view, but you are defining it as `vm.habitantId` in your controller.

Comment: Thanks. sorry i cant rate u(